# count unique values of a column for a given column in r

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame like

```
col1 col2  col3
A      2    b1 
A      3    b2
A      2    b2
A      2    b1
A      3    b2
```

I want to get the count of unique values of col3 for each combination of col1 and col2 as following

```
col1  col2 count_unique
 A       2         2
 A       3         1
```

What is the best one line solution to this?

Comment: `aggregate(col3~., df, function(x) length(unique(x)) )` but your desired output is wrong -- there's only one unique value for for col3 for the second row.

Comment: @Frank sorry about that. corrected it. and thanks for the solution.

Comment: @maj Sorry, I actually don't know at all; and just got there by trial and error looking at the examples at the bottom of the `?aggregate` documentation. I always use data.table for this: `setDT(df)[, uniqueN(col3), by=.(col1,col2)]`

Comment: [I just deleted my previous comment when I found an explanation for the dot in formulas. My comment read along the lines of "Would you please explain the formula you used?"] @Frank: Thanks.

Comment: @Frank Please consider to post that as a solution with the various options `df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% summarise(col3=n_distinct(col3))`

Comment: @akrun I have no problem with someone taking these variations and putting them into an answer. The q is probably a dupe, though, so I'm not putting up that effort myself.

Comment: @akrun Did you have anything specific in mind when you said "various options" (except base/data.table/dplyr)? Also, if you don't mind me asking here, should I rather look for duplicate questions than trying to answer when it feels like a duplicate?

Comment: @maj I meant the options that Frank suggested and the dplyr option (I showed).  If Frank says that there is a dupe.  I had also seen similar questions in the past.

Answer (score 3):

As @Frank and @akrun pointed out in their comments, there are several possible solutions to your question - here are three of the most used ones:

**in base R:**

```
aggregate(col3~., df, function(x) length(unique(x)) )
```

**using the data.table package (v1.9.5 and higher):**

```
setDT(df)[, uniqueN(col3), by=.(col1,col2)]
```

**using the dplyr package:**

```
df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% summarise(col3=n_distinct(col3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other two options:

#### plyr

```
library(plyr)
count(unique(df), vars = c("col1", "col2"))
```

Output:

```
 col1 col2 freq
1    A    2    2
2    A    3    1
```

#### sqldf

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(DISTINCT(col3)) n 
      FROM df GROUP BY col1, col2")
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 n
1    A    2 2
2    A    3 1
```